# Write additional variables to TensorFlow .pb file

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow

I am creating a TensorFlow model file (`.pb` file) from my weights and graph using `tf.train.write_graph()`.

I have a dictionary in Python `{'var1': [2, 5, 20], 'var2': 'blah', 'var3': 5}` that contains information nessecary for the post-processing I will be performing on the predictions outputted from my net. There are different values for the variables in the dictionary for each model (i.e. a different model will have a different value for `var1`, `var2`, etc. to adjust the post-processing algorithms to work for that specific model).

My question is this: Is there some way to embed this dictionary in the `.pb` file and retrieve it when loading a graph from the `.pb` file to consolidate everything? Otherwise I have to have a separate data file containing this information for each model file and that makes things cumbersome.